# Modify list of authors (`format.names` problem)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, apa-style

I am using natbib and started with `apa-good.bst` and was able to make minor modifications; for example use full-name instead of abbreviated :) But even after reading several tutorials on the "unnamed programming language" used to specify bst files, I can't figure the following out:

I currently have `{ll}, {ff}` for all authors with an `&` before the last; i.e.:

```
  Aurnague, Michel, Hickmann, Maya, & Vieu, Laure
```

But I want only the *first* to be `{ll}, {ff}` and after one comma all other authors should follow as `{ff} {ll}`; i.e.:

```
  Aurnague, Michel, Maya Hickmann & Laure Vieu
```

Any hints are greatly appreciated. My prof won't let me change the bibliography to anything consistent :|

Here is the current `format.names`:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}{, ff}{, jj}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              "," *
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                {
                  "\&"
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please indicate whether you use the `natbib` (or a related) citation management package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bibliography style file `apa-good.bst`, by default, indeed does not provide for different ordering of first and last names depending on whether or not the author/editor is listed first. Fortunately, though, adding this functionality isn't too hard to achieve.

Make a copy the file `apa-good.bst` and name the copy, say, `myapa-good.bst`. Then, in the function `format.names` (which starts on line 365 of my system's copy of this file, search for the following block of lines:

```
numnames 'namesleft :=
  { namesleft #0 > }
  { s nameptr
    "{vv~}{ll}{, ff}{, jj}"
    format.name$
    bibinfo bibinfo.check
```

and replace it with

```
numnames 'namesleft :=
  { namesleft #0 > }
  { s nameptr
    duplicate$ #1 >
      { "{ff }{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" }
      { "{vv~}{ll}{, ff}{, jj}" }
    if$
    format.name$
    bibinfo bibinfo.check
```

In these code snippets, I've already replaced `{, f.}` in the original bst file with `{, ff}` because you've indicated that you do *not* wish to abbreviate the authors' first names.

With this patch, you're instructing BibTeX to perform a check to see if the number of names of authors/editors left to be processed is greater than 1. If yes, it uses the formatting string `{ff }{vv~}{ll}{, jj}`; if no, i.e., if there's only one name left to be processed (which, because of BibTeX's "Reverse Polish Notation" method of handling the stack, must be the *first* author/editor), it uses the string `{vv~}{ll}{, ff}{, jj}`.

You should next store the new `.bst` file in a directory that's searched automatically by your TeX distribution and, if necessary, run `texhash` (or whichever command is appropriate for your TeX distribution) to update the distribution's filename database. Finally, be sure to issue the command

```
\bibliographystyle{myapa-good}
```

instead of `\bibliographystyle{apa-good}`.

Happy BibTeXing!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a switch to `biblatex` for two reasons. The first is the `biblatx-apa` attempts to be fully compliant with APA6. The second is that the formatting is defined with "standard" LaTex macros and not bst styles.

Comment: thanks, i will definitely switch to biblatex in the long run (this whole stackexchange seems to agree that it's just better and reasonably easy to switch, e.g.: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex ). i will accept your answer unless someone comes up with a code-fix the next days (i have to submit a chapter next week and won't be able to switch the whole project so quickly).

Comment: Also, `amsrefs` is quite nice (though it has fewer features than biblatex, it has a benefit of being *completely* written in TeX - no external programs required at all!)

Comment: While it is indeed the case that the `biblatex-apa` package makes every effort to make formatted references conform to the APA's guidelines, I wonder if that's what the OP is actually trying to achieve. After all, reversing the order of authors' first and last names would not appear to be something that's APA-compliant...